# Can someone check my proof about uniform convergence of a series.Please

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $\sum |a_k| < \infty$, show that

$$\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\right)dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k+1}.$$

---

I know I have to use the theorem that says,

If $f_k$  is  $\mathscr{R}[a,b] $ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and if $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x) , x \in [a,b],$ where the series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $ f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] $ and 
$\int_a ^b f(x) dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_a^b f_k(x) dx $.

---

**What I have done**,

Proof: for all $x \in [0,1] $ we have $|x| \leq 1$ , thus $|x|^k \leq 1$,  so $|a_kx^k| = |a_k||x|^k \leq |a_k|$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Since $\sum |a_k| < \infty $ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k $ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ by the Weierstrass M-Test. If $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ is the $n$th partial sum, then we see that the partial sums are polynomials and are therefore continuous on $[0,1]$, thus each $f_k \in \mathscr{R}[a,b]$. By the theorem we have 
\begin{align}
 \int_0^1 f(x)dx &= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k dx \\ 
&= \int_0^1 [ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k] dx\\ 
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 [ \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k] dx \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 a_kx^k dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 a_kx^k dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty [\frac {a_k}{k + 1}]
\end{align}
Can someone please examine my proof and let me know if it is correct or what errors I have made if any.

Answer (score 0):

In the second to last line the last expression should have $\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 a_k x^k dx$ but other than that the proof looks fine.

Comment: yeah that was a typo..but thanks for the feedback though.